# I have made incoming call receiver but truecaller is opening upon my activity.any suggestions to suppress truecaller

Tags: android, phone-call

I have made an incoming call reciever. Everything is working properly but the problem is that truecaller is opening upon my reciever due to which the UI of my receiver is somewhat hidden.

Any suggestions on how to suppress or kill TrueCaller?

Comment: Have you set TrueCaller as your standard call reciever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need inflate a overlay with WindowManager.

```
private void putOverlay(View view) {
        try {
            // Create Overlay
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            overlay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);


            final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(view, params);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logManager.error("SICS - Exception: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Something like this. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this method in onRecive Method

```
 abortBroadcast();
```

and give your reciver with highest prority so it will not call the rest of the broadcasts try it once.